# ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused from GUI but not from __name__ == '__main__'

Tags: python, sockets, http, user-interface, tkinter

I'm attempting to display raw HTML from pages using a HTTP socket connection, here is the backend.py file:

```
import socket


def get_page_data(address):
    page_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    page_socket.connect((address, 80))
    cmd = ('GET http://' + address + ' HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n').encode()
    page_socket.send(cmd)

    html = ''

    while True:
        data = page_socket.recv(512)
        if len(data) < 1:
            break
        html += str(data) + '\n'
    page_socket.close()
    return html


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(get_page_data('data.pr4e.org'))
```

When run it produces the appropriate data. When I run my GUI and enter the same address I get this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/owner/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_cpu/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/owner/PycharmProjects/shitty_browser/frontend.py", line 24, in <lambda>
    b1 = Button(master, text="Go To Page", command=lambda: find_page(url))
  File "/home/owner/PycharmProjects/shitty_browser/frontend.py", line 8, in find_page
    data = get_page_data(address)
  File "/home/owner/PycharmProjects/shitty_browser/backend.py", line 6, in get_page_data
    page_socket.connect((address, 80))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Here is my frontend.py file:

```
from tkinter import *
from backend import *

master = Tk()


def find_page(address):
    data = get_page_data(address)
    text = Text(master, text=data)
    text.grid(row=1, column=1)


master.title("Browser")
master.geometry("500x300")

Label(master, text="URL").grid(row=0)
e1 = Entry(master)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=4)

url = str(e1.get())

print(url)

b1 = Button(master, text="Go To Page", command=lambda: find_page(url))
b1.grid(row=0, column=6)


master.mainloop()
```

I guess I'm just wondering why one works, but the other doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out what the issue was, I was getting the string data from `e1` immediately when the window opened, thus `url` was an empty string. I've changed it so now `url = str(e1.get())` is inside `find_page`